# Basic statistics: outliers, mean, median

Tags: statistics

For a sample of data, I got that the mean = 4.31 and the median = 4.42. Also, 36% of the values from the sample are less than the mean. Does this illustrate that the data is skewed left?

Comment: I would say "indicate" rather than "illustrate", though it may depend on your definition of skewness

Comment: Also, I found 4 outliers from a method using mean and standard deviation and 5 outliers (4 were the same as before) from a method using quartiles. Does this indicate that these outliers are not significant?

Comment: Outliers is a different question: with mechanical identification it will depend on the underlying distribution and on sample size.

Comment: Can you help me understand this?

Comment: 4.37
4.56
4.26
4.56
4.3
4.46
3.84
4.57
4.26
4.37
3.49
4.43
4.48
4.01
4.29
4.42
4.23
4.42
4.23
3.49
4.29
4.29
4.42
4.49
4.38
4.42
4.29
4.38
4.22
3.48
4.38
4.56
4.45
3.49
4.23
4.62
4.53
4.45
4.53
4.43
4.38
4.45
4.5
4.45
4.55
4.45
4.42

Comment: Those are the 47 values in the sample. I need help understanding:

Comment: 1. Check the number of outliers using the
mean and standard deviation and indicate how many outliers are identified. Compare the results
using a outbox. What does this illustrate?

Comment: 2. What proportion of the
values are less than the mean? What does this illustrate?

Comment: It is better to add data (and related questions) to your question (not in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a histogram illustrating your data.

[image: histogram]

As you surmised from the summary statistics, this data distribution is left skewed and most of that skewness is caused by the four observations between $3.4$ and $3.5$.  Whether they or any others are faulty observations or not is for you to decide, but you should be reluctant to exclude them from the analysis without good reason.